# How do I create a table in Python? [rewritten, was a bit unclear]

Tags: python

I need a line of code that creates a table/list (whatever you'd like to call it) without having to write something like `table1 = []`. Is there a line of code that creates a table for you? I wanted to have a code, where everytime it creates a table, the table is empty and it's named is `dt`+`tablenum`. 'tablenum' being an integer that increases every time a new table is created.

EDIT: Rewrote the question to make it clearer. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do it? How would you access dynamically named variable? Is it an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. We would have to take wild guesses what you expect your table to look like and what you define as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create list or dict

```
dt = [] # list 
dt = {} # or dictionary
```

and then you can add new list

```
dt.append( [] ) # add to list
dt[tablenum] = [] # or add to dictionary
```

and you can access it using

```
print dt[tablenum] # list or dictionary

print dt[tablenum][element_number]

# or

for element in dt[tablenum]:
    print element

# or

alias = dt[tablenum]

for element in alias:
    print element
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm so annoyed that I couldn't think of such a simple solution. To access a single item in a table I'd do dt[num][num], right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect job for `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dt = defaultdict(list)

# adding items
dt[tablenum].append(item)   # if dt[tablenum] does not exist,
                            #  a new list is automatically created
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I believe 'listception' is more efficient haha.